# Does ::ng-deep override styles defined by classes at the child component level Angular 4/5

Tags: css, angular, shadow-dom

If I use :host ::deep button {...} and one or more of the children has a class defining styles for button, which one wins out?

Comment: you could just try this.

Comment: @bryan60 try what

Comment: what you're asking, open your command line, start a new project, generate a component, and put in some elements and some css and test it.